# Login failed for user (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 4064)

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014. Earlier I was able to connect with the server database. But somehow it stopped to get the login, Whenever I am trying to connect with the server database it gives an error message i.e. as follows.

Login failed for user (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 4064)

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not about changed the password.

Answer (score 5):

### Update

You may end up receiving this error when a Windows or SQL Server Login is not able to connect to the default database which is assigned to the user.
To Solve that error follow the following steps.

> First click on Option>> Button of “Connect to Server” Prompt.

[image: First click on Option>> Button of “Connect to Server” Prompt.]

> Now change the connect to database to any existing database on your
>   server like tempdb, msdb or master

[image]

> Now click on connect and it will successfully log you in.

Once you are connected to the SQL Server Instance execute the below TSQL to assign the login a new default database.

```
Use master
GO

ALTER LOGIN [MonitorDB] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = TempDB
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, for your suggestion but my question is why this database stop connecting while earlier I was able to connect and how could I connect the same database

Comment: There could be a million reasons. Your question doesn't contain any information that would suggest any one of them

Answer (score 2):

Error: 4064

```
select * from sys.messages where message_id = 4064
```

> Cannot open user default database. Login failed.

Change the default database to master or to an existing database.

Comment: Thanks, for your suggestion but my question is why this database stop connecting while earlier I was able to connect and how could I connect the same database

Comment: I can't know why - maybe the database doesn't exist on the server or it's offline, in restricted or single user mode

Comment: Yes, you are right it gives me Offline in database control panel

Comment: So, you should find out why it is and bring it online or change the user default database setting

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when database is dropped for which is default for some of the database user. When user try to login and their default database is dropped, SQL error 4064 shows up.

For workaround, Connect to

> SQL Server--> Click on Options 
>   -->Change Connect to database to existing database

and run following command:

```
ALTER LOGIN [xyz] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = master
GO
```

Replace xyz with your username and master with your database name.

Answer (score 0):

I am putting this here in case someone else stumbles upon it. In my case, it took turning on SQL Profiler to see what was going on. My connection to the database server as specified in my program's connection string was working fine. But the query had a join with a table on another linked SQL Server (four-part names), and the default database on the REMOTE server had been dropped.